# Showing data from controller in a grid view yii

Tags: php, yii

Is there a way of showing data from a controller in a `Grid` in my view.?
I am rendering a view and passing some data (array) with it how can i show them in a grid view..? is it possible at all?

Controller:

```
 $this->render('show_grid',array(
                                'site'=>$site,
                                'option1'=>$option1,
                                'option2'=>$option2,
                                'option3'=>$option3,
                                'option4'=>$option4,

                ));
```

Comment: do you want to show data in cgirview without dataprovider ?

Comment: @kumar_v yes, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a database which has the data. Then you can use the `CGridView` to show the grid(Example taken from documentation in [site](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)):

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post');

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
));
```

Comment: I want to show the values that i get from my controller, in a grid view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data as multi-demetional array as below:

```
 $rawData=array(

           array('id'=>1, 'username'=>'from', 'email'=>'array'),
           array('id'=>2, 'username'=>'test 2', 'email'=>'hello@example.com'),

       );
```

Check this link for complete example of passing data as array instead of Data provider.

http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/dataview/gridViewArray

Edi: for your case

```
$this->render('show_grid',array(
                                'site'=>$site,
                                'data'=>array(
                                'option1'=>$option1,
                                'option2'=>$option2,
                                'option3'=>$option3,
                                'option4'=>$option4,
                                )

                ));
```

Comment: Is there some way of doing it in my case.?
I am getting an array `option1`, which i want to display in one column, likewise for others.

Comment: You mean op1 | op2 | op3 | op4 .. etc?

Comment: Updated answer. Anyhow you have to check the link shared and make it work as per your requirment

Comment: have you fixed your problem?